# VBAでテキストボックスに入力された値のデータを参照したいです。

Tags: vba

図のようなもの作成しています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

従業員IDのところに参照したい従業員のIDを入力します。
参照ボタンを押すと、名前や交通手段などのデータが参照されます。

データの参照をするための文がわからず困っています。
また、ラジオボタンに参照させる方法も教えていただきたいです。

```
'参照ボタンを押した時の処理'
Private Sub ReferenceBtn_Click()

    'もし参照する値が入力されていなかったら'
    If Me.IDTextBox = "" Then
        MsgBox "参照する番号を入力してください。"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    i=

    '姓を出力'
    .Cells(i, 2) = Me.TextBox2

    '名を出力'
    .Cells(i, 3) = Me.TextBox3

    'セイを出力'
    .Cells(i, 4) = Me.TextBox4

    'メイを出力'
    .Cells(i, 5) = Me.TextBox5

    '性別を出力'
    .Cells(i, 6) =

    '交通手段を出力'
    .Cells(i, 7) = Me.ComboBox1

    '最寄り駅を出力'
    .Cells(i, 8) = Me.TextBox6

    '交通費を出力'
    .Cells(i, 9) = Me.TextBox7

    '時給を出力'
    .Cells(i, 10) = Me.TextBox8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Me.IDTextBox.Text`の記述でTextBoxコントロールのデータを参照することができます。(`Me`は省略可能です)

間違えやすいポイントは`IDTextBox`がTextBoxコントロールという入力欄そのものを表すことです。
一つ一つの入力欄はデータの他にName("IDTextBox"という識別名)、TopやLeft(フォーム内の配置座標)、TopやWidth(コントロールの大きさ)を表す**プロパティ**を持っています。

例えば`MsgBox IDTextBox.Width`と入力することでIDTextBoxコントロールの幅データを表示できます。
上記のようにTextも入力されたデータを管理するプロパティのひとつです。

またラジオボタンはチェック状態を`Value`プロパティで管理します。
`Value = True`ならば選択されている状態です。

複数のラジオボタンをグループ化して管理するために`GroupName`というプロパティも用意されています。
任意のラジオボタンをチェック状態にすると同一グループ名の他のラジオボタンは全てチェックが外れます。
性別のみ管理する場合は`GroupName`を設定しなくても普通に動きますが、性別以外にラジオボタンで管理する項目が増えた場合はグループごとに設定が必要です。

```
Private Sub ReferenceBtn_Click()
    If IDTextBox.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "参照する番号を入力してください。" 
        Exit Sub
    End If
    '1行目から最終行までループ
    For i = 1 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) + 1
        'IDが一致する行のみ処理
        Set ID = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
        If ID = IDTextBox.Text Then
            'TextBoxのTextプロパティを変更
            TextBox2.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
            'OptionButtonのValueプロパティを変更
            If Sheet1.Cells(i, 3) = "男" Then
                OptionButton1.Value = True
            Else
                OptionButton2.Value = True
            End If
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'プロパティウィンドウでGroupNameを設定してもOK
    OptionButton1.GroupName = "Sex" 
    OptionButton2.GroupName = "Sex" 
End Sub
```